# Is it possible to change the contents of __init__.py files of a module while runtime using python?

Tags: python

I need to change the precision value of the round function defined in the get_cpu_percent() in the psutil package. Is there any way to change this?

Comment: You can monkeypatch just about anything in Python; the `psutils.Process.cpu_percent()` method is no exception. But you'd have to copy the whole method source into the replacement. Wouldn't it be easier to just re-implement the method without patching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do this by subclassing `psutil.Process` in your own module, then override the method, e.g.

```
class MyProcess(psutil.Process):
    def get_cpu_percent(self, interval=0.1):
        return 42
```

However, in order to change the rounding you have to copy a lot of code since it is hard coded into `psutil`.

If you don't need the generality of the `get_cpu_percent` method, another option is to just define a new method in your subclass. You have `Process.get_cpu_times` to start with.

Python, being a dynamic language, allows you to replace the original implementation in the `psutil` class, but you should ask yourself if it is *really* needed.